# How to remove Midori from Elementary OS 0.2?

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04, midori

Sometime ago I met [Elementary OS](http://www.elementaryos.org/) and loved it, but it isn't stable yet.

Midori is the default browser of Elementary. If you go to "Applications" you can find and open Midori, but when you go to the Software Center you can't find it.

**I want to delete Midori because I prefer Chromium, but as I can't find it in the Software Center, how I can remove it?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### How to remove Midori browser from Elementary OS 0.2?

I don't know why you want remove Midori, but if you have this issue and really want remove Midori from your Elementary, you can follow these instructions:

1. Open your Software Center
2. In the search, type: "midori-granite"
3. Just click in "Remove" button of this item.

**Well done, your Midore browser was removed from Elementary!**

Comment: Q (by you) "... I want delete Midori because I prefer Chromium ..." A (by you) "... I don't know why you want remove Midori ...".  Split personality, or just a copypaste from some FAQ section?

Comment: hahaha, well, I just tried to show how a user would ask, and then as a user answer.

Comment: (I wrote the Q and A, I don't find it in any faq section).

Comment: It just struck me as a pretty odd way of writing stuff.  Now, please have a look [at the FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), I think this question should probably migrate to [superuser](http://superuser.com/) and voted to perform this migration automatically.

Answer (score 4):

You can easily remove midori from Freya by typing this command in your terminal:

```
sudo apt-get remove midori-granite
```

Cheers

Comment: The best answer every geek would love ... short and sweet.. It did the job right and Midori is gone..!!